# How do I reinforce a 96in long, 42in deep, 3/4in thick desk?

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, desk

Currently the desk is on two particle board legs from an Ikea style desk and I've reinforced it somewhat. But I have since upgraded to a larger monitor and can see my efforts has not faired too well.

I'm now thinking about redesigning the underside of the desk with some drawers and cable management channels. If possible I would prefer to maintain the two leg design with 60ish inches between each leg. I'll be picking out or making a new pair of legs for this as well.
[image: Image of the underside, to the best that I could capture. Support beams are 2x2in planks running the full length between the legs. Support with L brackets staggered on both sides]

Dimensions:
96in Long
42in Deep
3/4in Thick

60ish inches between legs, legs 2in thick, 42in long.

Weight Supported currently: About 30lbs in the center, and an additional 20ish lbs ontop of each leg.

[image: Image of the full desk (best that I could find)]

Comment: The drawers will be enclosed in a box with a piece of plywood at the back, right? That piece of plywood will act as a giant brace as long as you develop lots of strength at its connections. Your addition of drawers, then, ought to make the desk much more sturdy. You'll need to provide images if you want much better than that.

Comment: Desk top is made of regular wood planks. It is not plywood, nor particleboard or any other similar material. 

I received it from someone on facebook so I'm uncertain of which type of wood but I can say it's three rows with countersunk screws and wood glue connect the rows. 

Once I can do some clean up I'll grab some pictures but can't guarantee that anytime soon.

Comment: Three rows of 96" x 14".

Comment: Updated with photos @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact

Comment: @popham If having a piece of plywood backing is the best practice then that is what I will do, I've never made drawers before. To be completely transparent, cobbling this desk together is the extent of my "woodworking" capabilities thus far.

Comment: Can you buy or build two cabinets, throw out the legs, and put the desk surface on top of the cabinets?

Comment: Are the boards independent, or do they flex together?

Comment: @popham I most certainly could try this

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate they are screwed together (in my photo they're covered with wood filler) and glued together. They flex together.

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but it seems like a single adjustable leg, middle of the 8’, near the back would fix all your sag.

Comment: Putting a plywood sheet across the back would also alleviate the risk that a *sidewise* shove would collapse the leg, which appears unbraced. A rectangle (two legs, desktop and floor) easily collapses to a rhomboid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram

Comment: my desk has a 3/4" chipboard top,  what saves it is the two 3/4" square hollow steel bars  that run across it  about 5"  in from the front and back.

Comment: I zoomed in to check out the details on your "master race" desktop.

Comment: Would replacing the 2x2 with a steel box section give you enough stiffness for the desktop?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate You are right that would likely solve the issue but I would prefer to avoid that for looks.

Comment: I'm gonna give the "drawers-as-legs" with 2 sections of 2x2 square metal tubes running the length of the table top a go and a center section with a shorter 2x2 square metal tube. So something like 2x 30in wide drawer units, 1x center drawer unit. This way i increase the thickness of the desk by about 4-5 inches in the center and provide more stable legs without having to put anything vertical in the center of the desk

Comment: The wood strips used along with the brackets do not have enough lateral strength and are twisting under load. If you decide not to go with the drawers, use 4 strips of 3/4" Plywood 3" wide x desired length. Take two pieces and screw them together to make a beam. Repeat. Apply wood glue to the edge of the beam meeting the underside of the tabletop. Place one beam at the edge and the other at about the 1/3 width point from the edge. Use long screws to fasten through the beams into the tabletop. Allow the glue to set for a day before using.